# How can I move the position of the autoconnect arrow on Microsoft Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes

I am creating a new shape, a circle with a second text box on its side, and I would like to have the autoconnect arrow (the blue one that let you add a linked shape next to it) stay on the circle.

In other words, I keep the simple circle functionality, but each new one has the text inside it with a second text box beside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-connect arrows cannot be moved, they are positioned relative to the shape's outline. However, in a grouped shape, which is what you have, the group outline can vary. Try this (the exact details will depend upon which version of Visio you are using):
On a page add a circle, group the shape (use **Group -> Group**, not Convert to Group), now right-click and **Group -> Open Group**. You are now in the group editor. Now add your text box, when finished close the group edit window. Your shape will still have the select outline of just the original shape and will have the autoconnect properties you desire.